# Does Wireless Miracast Technology Exist For DisplayPort Computer Monitor?

Tags: wireless-networking, display, displayport, miracast

Is there a way to make a DisplayPort Monitor wireless? All the technologies only make HDMI Monitors be wireless such as this. Just curious if the technology has gone into DisplayPort.

[Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter P3Q-00001](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AZC3J3M)

(Looking for similar Miracast for Displayport)

Note: I have DisplayPort big monitor, and small laptop with both Displayport and HDMI connectors.

Comment: You are aware that Nvidia and AMD both have basically dropped supported for Miracast right?

Comment: hi  @Ramhound ok whats the replacement technology, why did they do that?

Comment: Some technologies are adopted by customers some are ignored.